# Selenium error : error response has status code 21

Tags: selenium

I am getting an error in **Selenium** :

```
error response has status code 21 and message, timed out waiting for page to load
```

Comment: We normally require you to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When did you get this error ? What are you trying to do ? Please elaborate your question ...